# Why does model converge when factors are releveled?

Tags: r, regression, logistic, mixed-model, corpus-linguistics

I am building a mixed effects logistic regression to predict linguistic (corpus) data. I have coded for various factors, some of which do not correspond to a large amount of data. For example, one predictor is Pauses with two levels [present, absent]. Pauses occur in only 11% of my data. When I insert all of my factors in a stepwise regression (using R base step function), the factor Pauses is selected as significant. However, when I put Pauses together with other factors in a mixed effects regression with a participant random intercept and a stimulus random intercept I have noted a strange behavior: Depending on the reference level selected for Pauses (e.g. if I relevel it to "absent"), including this factor in the overall mixed effects model will lead to non-convergence. When I relevel the factor to "present", it converges without a problem (and interestingly the factor turns out significant). I don't understand why this would happen in a binary factor like this. Conceptually, there should be no difference depending on which level this factor is releveled to (the only difference being what hypothesis I am testing with my data). If I understand correctly, all that should change in my regression is the coefficient. Does this indicate a problem with my model building or the data? Does it make sense to report in a paper the model with the factor leveled to the level that led to convergence?

Comment: Stepwise regression is a [really bad idea](https://towardsdatascience.com/stopping-stepwise-why-stepwise-selection-is-bad-and-what-you-should-use-instead-90818b3f52df). Convergence problems can have a multitude of reasons - please edit your post to give more details about the data and how they were collected, along with some of the actual, relevant, output of the models you are describing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some looking around, I believe the reason why the model converged (or not) depending on which reference level was chosen is **quasi-complete separation** (https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/other/mult-pkg/faq/general/faqwhat-is-complete-or-quasi-complete-separation-in-logisticprobit-regression-and-how-do-we-deal-with-them/). I ended up trusting the model results with the factors releveled in the way that made it converge.

Comment: if you have complete separation, then you should probably deal with that problem more directly (e.g. see https://bbolker.github.io/mixedmodels-misc/glmmFAQ.html#penalizationhandling-complete-separation )